# docker stack command is not in the list of docker command

Tags: docker

`docker stack` is not in the list of docker commands.

But it works fine. Is it a bug or what? Here is the command list of docker:

```
Management Commands:
  config      Manage Docker configs
  container   Manage containers
  image       Manage images
  network     Manage networks
  node        Manage Swarm nodes
  plugin      Manage plugins
  secret      Manage Docker secrets
  service     Manage services
  swarm       Manage Swarm
  system      Manage Docker
  trust       Manage trust on Docker images
  volume      Manage volumes

Commands:
  attach      Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container
  build       Build an image from a Dockerfile
  commit      Create a new image from a container's changes
  cp          Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
  create      Create a new container
  diff        Inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem
  events      Get real time events from the server
  exec        Run a command in a running container
  export      Export a container's filesystem as a tar archive
  history     Show the history of an image
  images      List images
  import      Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image
  info        Display system-wide information
  inspect     Return low-level information on Docker objects
  kill        Kill one or more running containers
  load        Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
  login       Log in to a Docker registry
  logout      Log out from a Docker registry
  logs        Fetch the logs of a container
  pause       Pause all processes within one or more containers
  port        List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container
  ps          List containers
  pull        Pull an image or a repository from a registry
  push        Push an image or a repository to a registry
  rename      Rename a container
  restart     Restart one or more containers
  rm          Remove one or more containers
  rmi         Remove one or more images
  run         Run a command in a new container
  save        Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
  search      Search the Docker Hub for images
  start       Start one or more stopped containers
  stats       Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
  stop        Stop one or more running containers
  tag         Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
  top         Display the running processes of a container
  unpause     Unpause all processes within one or more containers
  update      Update configuration of one or more containers
  version     Show the Docker version information
  wait        Block until one or more containers stop, then print their exit codes

Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

As you can see, there is no `stack` command.

Here is my docker version:

```
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker version
Client:
 Version:   18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:06:22 2018
 OS/Arch:   darwin/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.05.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.1
  Git commit:   f150324
  Built:    Wed May  9 22:20:42 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

**update 1**

I also think does `stack` command will show in a swarm node? So, I do a test using `docker-machine ssh myvm1 'docker'`. **Unfortunately, there is still no `stack` command**

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @novaline it seems like a bug in the documentation.

Also, if you try `docker stack --help`

You will get:

```
Usage:  docker stack COMMAND

Manage Docker stacks

Options:


Commands:
  deploy      Deploy a new stack or update an existing stack
  ls          List stacks
  ps          List the tasks in the stack
  rm          Remove one or more stacks
  services    List the services in the stack

Run 'docker stack COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is there, but...

```
$ docker stack ls
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

you have to run the Docker Engine in swarm mode.

from the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/):

> When running Docker Engine in swarm mode, you can use `docker stack deploy` to deploy a complete application stack to the swarm. The `deploy` command accepts a stack description in the form of a [Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).
>
> > **Note**: If you're trying things out on a local development environment, **you can put your engine into swarm mode** with `docker swarm init`.
> >
> > If you've already got a multi-node swarm running, keep in mind that all `docker stack` and `docker service` commands must be run from a **manager node**.

Comment: I know docker engine can be ran in single-host mode and swarm mode. `docker stack --help` works fine. So I think the point is why `stack` command is not show in the list? `docker stack ls`, `docker stack deploy`, `docker swarm init`, `docker-machine create -d virtualbox myvm1`, I think all of them is not my question ask.

Comment: I see your point. For some reason, they are not listed as available commands (even if swarm mode is enabled). Let's if a more experienced Docker user has the answer :)